# Example of a zero sequence $x_n$, such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

As stated in the title:
Let $x_n$ be a zero sequence, such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n}$ diverges.

- either: Find a sequence $x_n$ for which the condition is met.
- or: Prove that such a sequence cannot exist.

So far I have tried several known zero sequences: $\frac{1}{n},(\sqrt[n]{n}-1),\frac{n!}{n^n}$ but none seemed to work.
I also did not manage to prove that the statement is wrong. (I only managed to prove that for every zero sequence $x_n$ the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n^2}$ converges.)

I don't think blindly trying several zero sequences is the best idea, so I would like to know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about
$$x_n = \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} \quad ?$$

Comment: First of all, thanks I will try that. The thing is we haven't really introduced logarithms in the lecture yet, so I was thinking we should be able to solve this with what we have discussed so far. Do you think that the sequence must contain a logarithm?

Comment: I don’t think there’s any kind of simple answer that isn’t a disguised logarithm. An example is to take $x_n=1/k$ if $2^k < n \leq 2^{k+1}$.

Comment: @ghupftwieghatscht I am not sure that the sequence "must" contain a logarithm, but what is sure is that it has to tend to $0$ slower than any power of $n$. So a logarithm is the simplest sequence you can find in my opinion.